# How to automatically assign width to td based on the content of nested text box

Tags: html, css

I am just a beginner in  web development. I have searched throughly but didn't find a satisfactory answer although some alternative are available as I have mentioned below.

see this example http://jsfiddle.net/79aojg8m/4/

HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0" bgcolor="#00eeee">
 <tr>
  <td>HELLO THIS IS ME INSIDE THIS CELL 1</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="col2" style="width:100%; border:0; background: transparent; text-align: center;" value="HELLO THIS IS ME INSIDE THIS CELL">
  </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="col3"  value="Hello"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="col4"  value="World"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="col5"  value="H W"/></td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
table
{   
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid #b6e9f0;
 color: #0d5893;
 margin: 2%;    
 -moz-box-align: center;
 padding: 1em;      
 border-radius: 2em;
 background: #b6e9ff;
 overflow:auto;  
}


input,select,textarea
{
 font-size: 12pt;
 border: 0.1em solid black;
 width:60%;
 height: 2em;
 align: left;
 border-radius: 0.2em;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 margin-top: 2%;
 white-space: nowrap;
 box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

In above code the content of some columns are not displayed properly because all cell are assigned almost same width but, I want that the width of td should be equal to the width of child element content text(input value).

**An interesting thing to note is that cell is resizing automatically if there is no nested element inside `<td>`.**

Setting the width of both input and table to 100% solves the problem. But, I don't want to set the table width="100%" because it hampers with my UI design. Also `<td width="30%">` does the trick for that particular column but I don't want to set it manually, it should be done automatically.

So is there any way to resize td automatically as per input element content.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Would not it be like this then => https://jsfiddle.net/79aojg8m/8/

Comment: nope, i did not get what u want to say

Comment: Does this fiddle explain => https://jsfiddle.net/79aojg8m/10/ i think to get what you are trying to accomplish its better to use div with auto width and float left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through numerous post, i found out that table really does not work the way i wanted. so the only solution is to use text area so that the text can be displayed in multiple lines.

Following is the code:

HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0" bgcolor="#00eeee">
 <tr>
   <td>HELLO THIS IS ME INSIDE THIS CELL 1</td>
   <td><textarea name="col2"> HELLO THIS IS ME INSIDE THIS CELL</textarea>
   </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="col3"  value="Hello"/></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="col4"  value="World"/></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="col5"  value="H W"/></td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

CSS:

```
table
{   
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid #b6e9f0;
 color: #0d5893;
 margin: 2%;    
 -moz-box-align: center;
 padding: 1em;      
 border-radius: 2em;
 background: #b6e9ff;
 overflow:auto;

}


input,select,textarea
{
 font-size: 12pt;
 border: 0.1em solid black;
 width:60%;
 height: 2em;
 align: left;
 border-radius: 0.2em;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 margin-top: 2%;
 white-space: nowrap;
 box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

td textarea
{
  border:0;
  width:100%; 
  font-size: 8pt;
  background: transparent; 
  text-align: center;
  resize: none;
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
  white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
  word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
  white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap; /* Newer versions of Chrome/Safari*/
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align:sub;
 }
```

Or

If you want to assign fixed width then i had already mentioned solution in question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Table elements do not behave in this fashion as such but I believe this should do what your looking for. `white-space:nowrap;width:1%;`.

Comment: I is only working if i apply it to td selector in css but this spoils my format of other pages of same project. Hence i applied it by using `<td style="white-space:nowrap;width:1%;">` but of no use. Even after removing `width:1%` it does not solve problem completely.

Comment: why not use child selectors or give the specific td its own class.